# why use @{variableName} for bootstrap variables instead of @variableName

Tags: less

I'm looking at the bootstrap LESS source code and there is the following piece there:

```
.calc-grid-column(@index, @class, @type) when (@type = width) and (@index > 0) {
  .col-@{class}-@{index} {
    width: percentage((@index / @grid-columns));
  }
}
```

Why do they write `-@{class}` instead of simply `-@class`?

Comment: [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please add your comment as an answer so i can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by @Damien_The_Unbeliever Less enables you to use selector names, property names, URLs and @import statements. (also [attribute selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615585/dotless-lesscss-compiler-is-different-to-webessentials-lesscss-compiler)?).

The curly braces {} are used to make the variable name clear. In the case of `@ab` you can read variable `@a` or `@ab`. `@{a}b` forces that the variable `@a` will be used and has a string `b` appended.