# DotLess LessCss compiler is different to WebEssentials LessCss compiler

Tags: c#, css, less, dotless

I'm using dotless to parse LessCss at runtime. This is mostly successful but I have one scenario where it doesn't work as intended.

Given the following LessCss:

```
@tileWidth: 50px;
@tileMarginX: 5px;
@gridWidth: 2;

// recursive less to generate all x positions down to 1
.position-x(@maxIndex) when (@maxIndex > 0) {
    [data-col="@{maxIndex}"] {
        left: ((@maxIndex - 1) * @tileWidth) + (@tileMarginX * ((@maxIndex * 2) - 1));
    }

    .position-x(@maxIndex - 1);
}

.position-x(@gridWidth);
```

WebEssentials 2013 Update 3 will compile to:

```
[data-col="2"] {
  left: 65px;
}
[data-col="1"] {
  left: 5px;
}
```

LessEngine.TransformToCss will output:

```
[data-col="@{maxIndex}"] {
    left: 65px
}    
[data-col="@{maxIndex}"] {
    left: 5px
}
```

**Is this syntax not supported in DotLess?

How can I alter the Less code to get my expected output?**

Comment: Assuming `dotless` just does not support interpolation in attribute selectors: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6d1bc5483f43de3088b8#file-26615585-less) should do the trick I guess.

Comment: also see: https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/395

Comment: @seven-phases-max That's a perfect solution. I can confirm it works. Please place your comment as an answer so I can upvote and mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/395 `dotless` just does not support interpolation in attribute selectors so you need just "hide" the attribute in a variable, e.g.:

```
@tileWidth: 50px;
@tileMarginX: 5px;
@gridWidth: 2;

.position-x(@n) when (@n > 0) {
    @attr: ~'[data-col="@{n}"]';
    @{attr} {
        left: (@n - 1) * @tileWidth + (2 * @n - 1) * @tileMarginX;
    }

    .position-x(@n - 1);
}

.position-x(@gridWidth);
```